# How to create a multi-diagonal square matrix in Theano?

Tags: theano, diagonal

Is there a better way to create a multi-diagonal square matrix in theano than the following,

```
A = theano.tensor.nlinalg.AllocDiag(offset=0)(x)
A += theano.tensor.nlinalg.AllocDiag(offset=1)(x[:-1])
A += theano.tensor.nlinalg.AllocDiag(offset=-1)(x[1:])
```

where `x` is the vector i want on the diagonals? Each time i call `AllocDiag()()` a new Apply node is created which is causing memory issues and inefficiencies.

I'm hoping there is a way similar to scipy where a list of vectors can be passed into the function with a corresponding list of offsets, see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.diags.html.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way which doesn't require `AllocDiag()()` is to use `theano.tensor.set_subtensor()` with `A[range(n),range(n)]` to obtain the diagonal indexes where `A` is an `n*n`matrix . Something like the following:

```
A = tt.set_subtensor(A0[range(n),range(n)], x)
A = tt.set_subtensor(A[range(n-1),range(1,n)], x[:-1])
A = tt.set_subtensor(A[range(1,n),range(n-1), x[1:])
```

where `A0`is the initial matrix, for example, a matrix of zeros.